# Add current object value to the ChoiceType values if missing

Tags: php, symfony, events, symfony-3.3

I am currently converting an application to Symfony 3.3 and I am scratching my head as to how I can achieve the following.

I have a `ChoiceType` field, called `Responsible` (`String` values), which is populated from a database view. I expect to see the `Responsible` field already filled when going in edit mode, which is doing so when the record `Responsible` value is part of the `Responsible` field values.

But the values have changed since then, so when I get to edit an existing record, it will appear as **Please Select** when the value is not part of the already populated values.

My goal is to add that missing value to the `Responsible` field values so that it is pre-selected, but I couldn't find how yet.

I tried to see if there was an option in the `ChoiceType` [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/reference/forms/types/choice.html), but it seems like I have to go for the `onPreSetData` event to do so, but even there, I can only find how to dynamically add fields, not values to existing fields.

As anybody found out how to do so, and which is the "proper" way to do so?

Thanks.

**Edit**: Thanks to @matval answer, there was only missing something to find if the current value is in the choices so we don't have duplicate values, such as `if (!array_key_exists($entity->getResponsible(), $choices))`.

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // Some preceding code...

        // onPreSetData
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSet'))
}

/**
 * On pre set event.
 *
 * @param FormEvent $event
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function onPreSet(FormEvent $event)
{
    // Get entity & form
    $entity = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    // Fill choices with responsibles from the users table
    $choices = $this->fillResponsibles();

    // If the key does not exists in the choices, add it.
    if (!array_key_exists($entity->getResponsible(), $choices)) {
        $choices[$entity->getResponsible()] = $entity->getResponsible();
    }

    $form->add('responsible', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $choices,
        'placeholder' => '-- Please Select --',
        'label' => 'Responsible',
        'required' => false,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: You should post code to show us where you're at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form events are the proper way to do it. They are the best way to make dynamic forms. As you can see in the [symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class) you should add your `Responsible` field during the `PRE_SET_DATA` event.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $entity = $event->getData();
    $choices = ... // populate from db
    $choices[] = $entity->getResponsible();
    $form = $event->getForm();    
    $form->add('responsible', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $choices,
    ]);
});
```

If you want to keep dynamic field `Responsible` in your form type (maybe reuse for create action) you can still use the same event. All you need to do is remove the field and add it again.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $entity = $event->getData();
    $choices = ... // populate from db
    $choices[] = $entity->getResponsible();
    $form = $event->getForm(); 
    $form->add('responsible', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $choices,
    ]);
});
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks! I saw we could add form fields from an event, but was looking for a way to simply add the value. Anyway, it looks like doing so would be too complicated, so I'll simply leave the `Responsible` field in the `PreSet` event.

Comment: Note: using something like `if (!array_key_exists($entity->getResponsible(), $choices))` avoid duplicates in the choice field if the value was not missing.